# Global window numbers for all frames

Tags: window, frames

I am using window-numbering.el to switch between windows in a frame. However if I have multiple frames each frame starts numbering its windows beginning with 1. Is there a way I can have global window numbers over all frames, so that window numbering jumps between frames as well?

Comment: I only use one frame so I'm not sure about the following, but what you want might be possible with [`ace-window`](https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window).

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then command `icicle-choose-window-by-name` with `C-u` lets you choose a window, on any frame, by its name.

A window is named by its buffer.  If there is more than one window displaying the same buffer then the window name includes a suffix `[N]` (*N* = 2,3,...), to make it a unique name.

(The prefix arg you use determines whether to choose from windows on only the selected frame, on all visible frames, or all frames (including iconified and invisible frames).)